# Check if SDL Window is open

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl

I need to check if the game's SDL Window is open before I can start rendering graphics, normally I would know how to this, but the problem is the window is created in the main class, and I need to check if the window is open in the menu class. How do I check if the window is open in an entirely different class?

Comment: Hi from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40213616/3233393)! Just a heads-up about crossposting to multiple stacks: [it is quite strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). About your question, the simplest approach is storing your window pointer inside a global variable :)

Comment: Voting to close this; it doesn't seem specific to game development (despite SDL) but is rather a case of sharing state between classes, which is a generic C++ problem.

Comment: @LeComte a generic Object oriented problem, if you want to be more specific

Comment: How would you do it in the main class? In which class is the menu instance created?

Answer (score 2):

You dont specify if you are using SDL 1.2, or SDL 2.
I will explain it with SDL 1.2.

When yo do a

```
SDL_Surface* = SDL_SetVideoMode(Params...);
```

to create the window, you set the pointer of the window created in your SDL_Surface* SDL variable.

The function has two returns.

If has been executed successfully, it will return the pointer of the window.
If has NOT been executed successfully, it will return 'NULL';

So, yo need to check if the windows was created checking that pointer.
I will copy a segment of my code in SDL:

```
    Window = SDL_SetVideoMode(WindowWidth, WindowHeigth,Bpp, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE);    /// Asigno al Window el puntero asignado de la pantalla creada

    if( Window == NULL )    /// Window inicializado con error
    {
        if(Is_Open) { Log("Inicialize Window error"); } if(Is_Open) { Log(SDL_GetError()); }
        if(Is_Open) { Log("Window", Window); }
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Try to read the documentation for each function. Its not hard.
Docs
for SDL 1.2: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/
for SDL 2: https://wiki.libsdl.org/

And if you are using different functions you have 2 choices, make the variable of the window Global, or, passing by parameter to all your functions.

PD: Sorry for my english!